# Migrate Air encryptedlocalstorage to android sharedprefs

Tags: android, apache-flex, air

I'm working on an update to an android application, which was build using adobe air.
The update focuses on a rewrite from air technology to native android SDK.
However I want the user data saved in the encryptedlocalstorage to be persist in the new update.

Any idea on how to get the access of the encryptedlocalstorage from android SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have a hard time making this functionality work.  The ELS for Adobe Air is not accessible outside of the Air Application.  See this link for reference. [Adobe ELS Help Page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e31.html)

There is really no clean solution to this problem if you are trying to use the Adobe ELS and the Android Native SDK.  Android SDK offers a Cipher Class that will allow to  encrypt data and then store it on the device locally.  This is most likely your best bet to solve your problem.